# How to remove empty partial view on submit ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my web application, I have more than 5 partial views in the main view.

So the partial views are controlled from the Drop down menu. With the value of the drop-down menu, I hide and show the related partial view on the main view.

The process is when I click the button it loads the partial view. If I want to add another record I can add it by clicking the `Add New Record` button. If I want to remove it I can delete the partial view.

The issue is If I add a new record and load the partial view and If I don't want it I removed the record, But when It submits the main form I return an error and that deleted partial view shows again.

Can I know how to delete it completely?

This is How I load the partial view in the Main view.

```
<fieldset id="pnlGeneralItms" style="display:@(Model.GeneralItmsList == null || Model.GeneralItmsList.Count == 0? " none":"")">
  <legend>
    <h5>General Request Attachments / Bills</h5>
  </legend>
  <ul id="RequItms" style="list-style-type: none"> @if (Model != null && Model.GeneralItmsList != null) { foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.GeneralItms Itms in Model.GeneralItmsList) { Html.RenderPartial("_GeneralItms", Itms); } } </ul>
  <button type="button" id="addAnotherItm" class="btn btn-info" href="#">Add New Record</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#addAnotherItm").click(function() {
        $.get('/AppRequests/GeneralItmsPartialView', function(template) {
          $("#RequItms").append(template);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  <hr />
  <br />
</fieldset>
```

This is the Partial View

```
<li style="padding-bottom:15px"> @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("GeneralItmsList")) { @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TempID) @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group"> Type Line Description <div class="col-md-10"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attachment_Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Make it short" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attachment_Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group"> Attachment Amount <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Rs.</span> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attachment_Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
          </div> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attachment_Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Remove</button>
  </div> } </li>
```

This is how it shows. Even if I delete the highlighted record in submitting it returns the view with the deleted record.

[image]

[image]

Edited____

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create(AppRequest appRequest) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      if (appRequest.ApprovalPartyList?.ToString() != null) {
 
        if (appRequest.GeneralItmsList != null) {
          foreach(GeneralItms item in appRequest.GeneralItmsList) {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData" + item.TempID];
            item.Attachment = ConvertToBytes(file);
            item.FileType = Path.GetFileName(file.ContentType);
          }
 
          appRequest.General = new List < General > () {
            new General {
 
              GeneralItms = appRequest.GeneralItmsList,
 
            }
          };
 
        }
 
      }
 
      appRequest.Req_By = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
      appRequest.Company_Id = int.Parse((User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "CompanyID").FirstOrDefault().Value);
      appRequest.Create_By = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
      appRequest.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;
      appRequest.Modified_By = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
      appRequest.Modified_Date = DateTime.Now;
      appRequest.Status = true;
      try {
        db.AppRequest.Add(appRequest);
        db.SaveChanges();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
 
        TempData["msg"] = "error";
        return View(appRequest);
      }
```

This is the Model

```
public class AppRequest {
  private zSqlDb db = new zSqlDb();
 
  [Key]
  public int Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Request Type")]
  public int ReqType {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Requesting By")]
  public int Req_By {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Requesting Date")]
  public DateTime Req_Date {
    get;
    set;
  } = DateTime.Now;
 
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Request Location")]
  public int Req_Location {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Request Heading")]
  public string Req_Heading {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Display(Name = "Cover Note")]
  public string Req_CoverNote {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
  public int Company_Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public bool Status {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public int Create_By {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public DateTime Created_Date {
    get;
    set;
  } = DateTime.Now;
  public int Modified_By {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public DateTime Modified_Date {
    get;
    set;
  } = DateTime.Now;
  public int Approval_Status {
    get;
    set;
  }
   
  public virtual IList < General > General {
    get;
    set;
  }
  
   
  #region ILists
 
    //General
    [NotMapped]
  public IList < GeneralItms > GeneralItmsList {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  #endregion
 
    [NotMapped]
  public int xSupp_Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
}
 
#region General
public class General {
  [Key]
  public int Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  [ForeignKey("AppRequest")]
  public int Req_Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public virtual AppRequest AppRequest {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  public string ApprovedNumber {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  public bool IsSettled {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  public virtual IList < GeneralItms > GeneralItms {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
public class GeneralItms {
  [Key]
  public int Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  [ForeignKey("General")]
 
  public int General_Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  public virtual General General {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public byte[] Attachment {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  public string FileType {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
  [Required]
  public string Attachment_Description {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public decimal Attachment_Amount {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public bool Status {
    get;
    set;
  } = true;
  public bool IsApproved {
    get;
    set;
  } = false;
 
  [NotMapped]
  public int TempID {
    get;
    set;
  }
 
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you save and delete the information stored?

**Edit** i think that you just remove from the ui only and not the record you saved.

**Edit 2** so as i told you before. you are saving the information in a Database. For you to actually remove that view you need to remove that row from the database as you did with save here.
[image]

Comment: Yes I think thats the case. When it removed it removed from the ui. Is there any way to delete the partial view permanently

Comment: Where do you store the information for link description and attachment amount?

Comment: In the model I have created a IList. So when submits the main view the added informationa goes to the controller from there.

Comment: And then from the controller to a database? if that is the case then you will need to remove that row from the database.

Comment: but the thing is when the request comes to the controller, model state becomes false because of the empty raw. Then it returns to the view again. So need to know a way to delete permanently the partial view when user deletes it from the view

Comment: is it possible for you to share an example project? i cant really understand how you do it and how your delete work.

Comment: I updated the question with GIF. Please check it. You can see there, First I add a partial view and named it as an Active line, And then I added another one I mentioned that as ``Deleted line``, then I delete that partial view. When I Submit it, returns, and then you can see the deleted raw is there and in the controller, it returns because the controller counts it as a not deleted raw.  So I wanna remove the partial view permanently once I remove it.

Comment: Hello i understood that much... my question is where is this Model.GeneralItmsList getting the information from. As i can tell when the submit happen it will load the *deleted item* as it is not deleted... it is just removed from the Interface using javascript. Can you show how you get the information on `Model.GeneralItmsList`

Comment: I have updated the question, I added the model and the controller

Comment: updated my answer with **edit 2**